# Inserting a range of values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert a range of values in table. Eg:Bloodglucose,Insulin. The bloodglucose for the range 70-130 is 0units. 131-180 is 2units. Similarly it goes on. How can I specify it in mysql query in a single statement to insert the range of values?

Comment: Pls provide sample data how it should look like in your table. At the moment I do not understand what you are after.

Comment: BG-71   Insulin-0,BG-72 Insulin-0,BG-73 Insulin-0,........BG-130 Insulin-0

Answer (score 0):

You may store sides of range in a differens fields.

It's also possible to store range as a string but it's a very limited idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper normalized table

```
eg: your_table('param', min_value, max_value, result)
```

and an insert with bulk values

```
insert into your_table('param', min_value, max_value, result)
values ('bloodglucose', 70, 130, '0units'), 
      ('bloodglucose', 131, 180, '2units'),
      ........
      ('bloodglucose', nnn, mmmm, 'xxxxxxx')
  ;
```

Comment: Right of syntax to use near''param... is the syntax error

Answer (score 0):

```
AmbassadorID = 
     CASE
        WHEN values <= 130 and values >= 70 THEN '0'
        WHEN values <= 180 and values >= 131 THEN '2'
     END
```

Comment: This is just a part of sql query that you must need it